# Highlightjs doesn't show code for html and handelbars

Tags: javascript, highlightjs

I m using Highlight.js from NPM and I would like to have html and handelbar templates code showing on screen. I confirm it works perfectly for JS code but it doesn't show code for html and handelbars. For example below code, I expect to display the html on screen but it doesn't...

My html code:

```
<pre><code><button>Click</button></code></pre>
```

My js code

```
hljs.initHighlightingOnLoad();

$('pre code').each( (i, block) => {
  console.log(block);
  hljs.highlightBlock(block);
});
```

The html when inspect view source:

```
<pre><code class="handelbars hljs ebnf"><button><span class="hljs-attribute"><span class="hljs-attribute">Click</span></span></button></code></pre>
```

What is showing on page is just a text 'Click'

[image]

Does anyone know how to get it working?